# Group , Order , Limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this script :

```
 $limit1=10; 
 $MySQL=mysql_connect($myhost,$myuser,$mypass);
    mysql_select_db($sitedb);
    $rank = mysql_query('SELECT usrid,num FROM 7stat '.' GROUP BY usrid ORDER BY num desc LIMIT '.$limit1.''); 
    $i=1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rank)) 
    {
    echo '<tr>
       <td align="center">'.$row['usrid'].'</td><br>
      <td align="center">'.$row['num'].'</td>
    </tr> ';
    $i++;
    }
```

Basically should show me top 10 surfers but it does not . 
In this page can be found the results : 
http://123autotraffic.com/12.php

Check last table .

My user ID : 1

I made today 840 credits ( num ) and from start over 30000  but the script shows 52 .

Please help .

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `7stat` (
  `usrid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `num` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usrid`,`date`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have to use group because it is a monthly statistic
If is not grouped will show the same user id more times .

Fixed . Big thanks to everyone .

Comment: Please run the query directly against the DB and show the output.

Comment: why do you need to use GROUP BY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the query in your script:

```
$rank = mysql_query('SELECT `usrid`, SUM(`num`) AS mysum FROM `7stat`
                       GROUP BY `usrid` ORDER BY mysum DESC LIMIT '.$limit1);
```

And replace everywhere in your code:

```
$row['num']
```

With:

```
$row['mysum']
```

Comment: Did you replace the line in your script?

Comment: @Gerculy Robert You also need to change your `echo` statement to `<td align="center">'.$row['mysum'].'</td>`.

Comment: I replace <td align="center">'.$row['num'].'</td> with 
 <td align="center">'.$row['mysum'].'</td> but still nothing ..

Comment: Can you try with `MAX(num)` instead of `SUM(num)`  ?

Comment: add echo mysql_error(); after mysql_query(...); what does it display?